# socket_io working with multiple processes and ports

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am creating 2 subprocesses in my server.py:

```
@app.route("/dataVis", methods=['POST'])
def draw():
    config_data = {
    "/dev/tty.BITalino-73-36-DevB": {
        "port": 8020
    },
    "/dev/tty.BITalino-6E-2A-DevB": {
        "port": 8020
    }
    }

    for macAddress in list(config_data.keys()):
        subprocess.Popen("python client.py " + macAddress + " " + str(port) + " " + str(channels) + " " + str(SR) + " " + str(nSamples), shell=True)
    return render_template("realTimeDataVis.html", host_ip=json.dumps(str(host_ip)))
```

Listening possibly to different ports according to the argument given. Then in client.py I have:

```
PORT = sys.argv[2]
with SocketIO(host_ip, PORT, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
   socketIO.emit('dataReceiver', send_data) # send data
```

which sends the data back to server.py, namely:

```
@socket_io.on('dataReceiver')
def drawer(data):
   emit('draw', send_data, broadcast=True)
```

Which emits my data to my javascript file:

```
var sock = io.connect(IP);
sock.on('draw', function(data){...}
```

My code is currently working for one process only. Should I try to use 2 different ports? How do I do so?

Comment: No I don't think you need many ports, a single port can receive any number of connections.

Comment: Are you monitoring the output of the child processes? Any errors should appear there. For starters, you cannot start two servers on the same port.